# Android Scan BLE Devices, problem after update Android Studio and/or upgrade targetSDK to 9.0

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an app already published, targetSDK 6, minSDK 5. This app use BLE API and I using this code

```
final BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();

List<ScanFilter> scanFilters = new ArrayList<>();

ScanSettings.Builder builder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
builder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_OPPORTUNISTIC);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
    builder.setCallbackType(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)
    builder.setLegacy(true);

final ScanSettings settings = builder.build();

bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanFilters, settings, mScanCallback);
```

now I upgraded Android Studio for Build Tool Versione 28.0.3

- Compile SDK Version API 28 (Pie 9)
- Target SDK Version API 28
- Min SDK API 23 (Marshmallow 6)

My BLE Device uses bluetooth ble 4.1

All compile...ok....but! I try to scan but it doesn't find anymore devices....
no error, no exception....simply not find anything.

can someone help me understand?
help!

Comment: Are you sure permissions such as COARSE & FINE LOCATION are set correctly?  That's what I'm fighting.

Comment: Oh, and what Android device are you using?  Is it Pie (9.0)?   I updated my app to newer SDKs (not as  new as yours) and works on Oreo devices, but not on the Pie device.  The Pie runs the older app fine.

Comment: Pie has BLE and BT issues: see
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/phone-by-google/Pi-yHYArYCk
or 
https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Android-App/Android-9-0-Pie-not-able-to-sync/td-p/2889550